# How to set keybindings to jump to next/previous latex math environment?

Tags: org-mode, latex, auctex

In vim (I think with vimtex) one can jump to the next or previous math zone (inline or display mode) with a keybinding.

Using auctex or org mode (preferably org mode), how could one do that in emacs ? Are there packages that could help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on the AUCTeX part.

There are many packages aimed at this question, such as https://github.com/Malabarba/latex-extra and https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens.

I wasn't fully satisfied with the available options, so I wrote https://github.com/ultronozm/tex-parens.el, which provides commands for navigating between math zones, environments and math-like delimiters in much the same way that stock Emacs allows you to navigate between parenthesized groups.  If you set that package up and use the same binds that I do, then you can use `tp-forward-list` (`C-M-n`) and `tp-backward-list` (`C-M-p`) to navigate between math expressions, and `tp-down-list` (`C-M-g`) and `tp-up-list` (`C-M-u`) to enter and exit those expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am an emacs beginner and do not currently have a lot of time available, it would be difficult for me to try to understand the package you wrote. However, as you mentioned related links, I would like to mention that it might be also possible using tree-sitter as there seems to be a latex option for that. Maybe the following package for tree sitter editing and navigation (I did not read the code nor tried it yet) could help https://github.com/mickeynp/combobulate

Comment: You don't need to understand the package.  You just need to install it.  If you have questions about how to do that, then please ask.